# Power Automate HTTP request to get groups and permission levels associated with them

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I am using the HTTP request in power automate below to get a list of permissions groups for my site. In addition I would like to get the groups permission level / role id by name. How could this be done?

[image]